# while loop inside of a while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, addition

I am pretty sure that you can put a while loop inside of a while loop, as i have done it before, but i seem to be running into a problem here. As this is pretty complex, ill post my code then explain it.

PHP:

```
//post vars
$port=$_POST['ports'];
$super=$_POST['super'];
$col=$_POST['columns'];
$row=$_POST['rows'];
//rest of vars
$half_col=$col/$super;
$halfer_col=$col/$super;
$i=1;
$count=1;
$and=1;
$one=1;
$sector=array();
$dat_array=array();

echo $port."<br>";

echo $super."<br>";

echo $col."<br>";

echo $row."<br><br><br><br>";
echo "<h1>here goes nothen</h1><br><br>";

while($count<$port){
    while($i<=$half_col){
        $dat_array[]=$halfer_col;
        $i+=$and;
        $halfer_col-=$and;
        echo "<br>halfer_col:".$halfer_col."<br>";
    }
print_r($dat_array);
$sector[]=implode(',',$dat_array);
$count+=$half_col;
$halfer_col+=$half_col;
}

echo "<br><br>ANNNNNNND...<br><br>";
print_r($sector);
```

Now, this is with user input port:24 super:2 col:12 row:2
result:

```
24
2
12
2

here goes nothen

halfer_col:5

halfer_col:4

halfer_col:3

halfer_col:2

halfer_col:1

halfer_col:0
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 5 [2] => 4 [3] => 3 [4] => 2 [5] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 5 [2] => 4 [3] => 3 [4] => 2 [5] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 5 [2] => 4 [3] => 3 [4] => 2 [5] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 5 [2] => 4 [3] => 3 [4] => 2 [5] => 1 ) 

ANNNNNNND...

Array ( [0] => 6,5,4,3,2,1 [1] => 6,5,4,3,2,1 [2] => 6,5,4,3,2,1 [3] => 6,5,4,3,2,1 )
```

basically, it takes the user input, breaks it down and implodes it in the prober order based on a ",". however from what i can tell, it is not adding here: `$halfer_col+=$half_col;` and that is causing the data to not increment, any ideas anyone? Or even an explanation as to why that will not add and affect my internal while loop the way that it is set.

in the end the final array should look like so:

```
Array ( [0] => 6,5,4,3,2,1 [1] => 12,11,10,9,8,7 [2] => 18,17,16,15,14,13 [3] => 24,23,22,21,20,19 )
```

Comment: What output do you want? (there might be another way of doing it)

Comment: Maybe you meant to restart the inner loop with $i = 1 every time? As it is now, $i is only less than $half_col during the first time the outer loop runs.

Comment: @h2ooooooo i added what the final print array should look like

Comment: @MrLister i tried reseting $i and the end of the outer while loop but the only thing that changes was that it addied 1 extra array output to each array. if that makes sense

Comment: Then it's not clear what you want. After the first (and only) time the inner loop runs, it start adding to halfer_col, but halfer_col isn't used any more after that.

Comment: @MrLister I guess the next question is, how would you recomend running the while inner loop again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your code to the following:

```
$port = (int)$_POST['ports'];
$super = (int)$_POST['super'];
$col = (int)$_POST['columns'];
$row = (int)$_POST['rows'];

$colHalf = $col / $super;

$finalArray = array();
for ($i = $port; $i >= 1; $i -= $colHalf) {
    $tempArray = array();
    for ($j = 0; $j < $colHalf; $j++) {
        $tempArray[] = $i - $j;
    }
    $finalArray[] = implode(",", $tempArray);
}
$finalArray = array_reverse($finalArray);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($finalArray, true) . "</pre>";
```

This will print what you want (port = 24, super = 2, col = 12, row = 2):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6,5,4,3,2,1
    [1] => 12,11,10,9,8,7
    [2] => 18,17,16,15,14,13
    [3] => 24,23,22,21,20,19
)
```

Comment: Worked great thanks! Were you by any chance able to tell what is wrong with mine?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the outer while a for loop.

```
for(; $count<$port; $count+=$half_col){
    while($i<=$half_col){
        $dat_array[]=$halfer_col;
        $i+=$and;
        $halfer_col-=$and;
        echo "<br>halfer_col:".$halfer_col."<br>";
    }
print_r($dat_array);
$sector[]=implode(',',$dat_array);
$halfer_col+=$half_col;
}
```

Comment: I pondered the idea of a for loop but i couldnt think of a way for it to work. i just tried it that way and the output was the same^